# angular mdc-select looks completely unstyled, button looks fine

Tags: angular

I created a new angular projec, I did the steps here: https://trimox.github.io/angular-mdc-web/#/angular-mdc-web/getting-started

Why does my mdc-select look like this

[image: reality]

instead of this

[image: expectations]

Button looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `styles.scss` file, then restart your app

```
@use '@material/select/mdc-select';
@use '@material/select/_index' as select;
@use '@material/list/mdc-list';
@use '@material/menu-surface/mdc-menu-surface';
@use '@material/menu/mdc-menu';
```